# ImportError: No module named psutil while using robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using robotframework for automation. I'm trying to use a method from my python library which needs psutil. The problem is when I execute from the robotframwork it gives error `ImportError: No module named psutil`  but when I execute it with Pycharm I don't get any error. I have installed psutil using `pip install psutil` . I searched a lot on web but couldn't find any reason for this issue.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question.  It runs without issue from PyCharm but doing so from within robotframework in a command line it throws the above error?

Comment: Yes. I'm importing python library in RF which has psutil lib. So, while running the test script on RF, I get an ImportError on RF. Just to try my function (which has psutil) in Pycharm, I'm able to run the function without any error. So, I concluded that RF is throwing error and my function by itself is working. Do you need to see the code?

Comment: yes code is needed otherwise we're just guessing.  Also please give the exact execution statements you're running.  When you say calling from RF, are you running from within pycharm again?

Answer (score 2):

My experience with this error was that I had multiple versions of python installed on my ubuntu server 16.04LTS.

My PATH resolved to `/usr/local/python` -> python 2.7.10 meaning typing python into the commandline I got 2.7.10, but the standard path `/usr/bin/python` linked to python 2.7.12.  The psutil module and others were only installed for version 2.7.10

My resolution was to re-symlink `/usr/bin/python` to point to my 2.7.10 version:

```
# Find which python your PATH is pointing at and the version
$ which python

# Returns
/usr/local/bin/python

$ /usr/local/bin/python --version

# Returns
Python 2.7.10

$ /usr/bin/python --version

# Returns
Python 2.7.12
```

Unlink and relink to correct python version in `/usr/bin/python`
    $ cd /usr/bin
    $ sudo unlink python
    $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python python

```
# check python version points correctly
$ /usr/bin/python --version

# Now correctly returns 
Python 2.7.10
```

**P.s.** Bear in mind it's still worth checking all your modules are correctly installed now that your environment is pointing at the 1 python version

Answer (score 1):

Could you try setting the PYTHONPATH in your environment or by passing it as an option.

This person had a different issue, but the fix I think will be the same:

[setup pythonpath before starting test suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573608/setup-pythonpath-before-starting-test-suite)

Cheers,

K